# Cannot add a class to body tag in lwc

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, css, web-components

I am trying to add `'overflow: hidden !important'` property in body tag of lightning page.

For this, i did the following

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden !important'
```

Unfortunately, it didnot work. 
The style should be applied when a popup opens.
Any idea on how i can do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in LWC, because of the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_dom), as well as the [Locker Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_code.htm). If you're running a "full screen app" (e.g. the top-level component is in a Lightning App), you could put this style on the top-level component, but if you're in the Lightning Experience, you wouldn't be able to do this.

Comment: I want to use overflow: hidden style because i wanted to hide scrollbar from record page (lightning experience). This needs to be done when a modal popup opens. Any idea on how i can do this?

Comment: @lambad Again, you can't. It's a limitation because of security restrictions. If you could access the DOM at will, you'd be able to create all sorts of malicious components. To limit the mischief one can do, security is strictly enforced.

Comment: I was able to add style to body tag by doing document.body.style.position = 'fixed';
Do you think this this is an issue in salesforce?

Comment: @lambad As I understand it, it shouldn't be possible, but perhaps I've overlooked something. I'll try it tonight and get back to you.

Comment: This is a frustrating limitation and one Salesforce should never prevent users from doing

Answer (score 1):

document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';

Remove the 'important'. It worked for me.